# How to choose a certain string out of an array

Tags: php

I was wondering how to choose a certain string out of and array. Say this this is my array:

```
$a=array("What Color is the sky?","How are you?","Can you spell 'the'?");
```

how would I echo just the first string?

Comment: This is a very basic question, please check the manual http://us3.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would do it that way:

```
echo $a[0];
```

a[index] where index represent the "cell" position. If you want the second string, you'd do:

```
echo $a[1];
```

Comment: Thanks,  I'm just starting out in PHP, so I'm still learning the basics.

Comment: No problem. However, try searching on php docs, or tutorials. There's plenty good of them. Also, if my solution did work, please flag it s answered :)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to print the first value and not worry what key (numeric or associated) is the first one, use "current" ([read on current function on php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.current.php)). It returns the current element of the array, i.e. the element, on which the array "cursor" is currently at:

```
$a = array("What Color is the sky?","How are you?","Can you spell 'the'?");
echo current($a);
```

You can still use key function to print all of them:

```
$a = array("What Color is the sky?","How are you?","Can you spell 'the'?");
while(FALSE !== next($a)) {
   echo current($a) . '<br />;
}
```

While using current(), key(), next() and similar functions, remember to use reset($arr) to reset the position of the pointer in array.